# how to set filter from another view?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3

```
std::vector v1 {4,2,7,6,4,1};
std::vector v2 {3,0,0,0,0,3};
```

I want to get the values in v1 with the condition v2=3

my desired result [4,1]

I tried with filter but it seems to work only with a specified value.

```
auto rng = v1 | ranges::views::filter([](int x){return ...;});
```

How can I do this without using for-loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be something along these lines:

- `zip` `v1` and `v2`,
- `filter` based on the `.second` of each element with the condition you like
- `transform` to only retain the `.first` of the survived elements

[Here's a working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v33cfhffd):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/zip.hpp>

using namespace ranges::views;

int main() {
    std::vector v1 {4,2,7,6,4,1};
    std::vector v2 {3,0,0,0,0,3};
    auto result = zip(v1, v2) | filter([](auto pair){ return pair.second == 3; })
                              | transform([](auto pair){ return pair.first; });
    std::cout << result << std::endl; // prints [4,1]
}
```

### Some improvement

Notice that `[](auto pair){ return pair.first; }` is simply a lambda that runs `std::get<0>` on its input `std::pair`.

Unfortunately `std::get<0>` can't stand on its own, because there are several overlods of it (for `std::pair`, `std::tuple`, `std::array`, `std::variant`).

One way to streamline the code would be to

```
#include <boost/hof/lift.hpp>
```

and then define

```
template<std::size_t N>
auto constexpr get = BOOST_HOF_LIFT(std::get<N>);
```

so that you can pass `get<0>` around easily.

Given this, and with the help of [`boost::hana::compose`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-functional.html#ga3b16146e53efcdf9ecbb9a7b21f8cd0b) and [`boost::hana::curry`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-functional.html#ga49ea872ade5ac8f6c10052c495302e89) one can write this a curried version of `std::equal_to<>{}`

```cpp
    auto constexpr equal_to = curry<2>(std::equal_to<>{});
```

and come up with this:

```cpp
    auto result = zip(v1, v2) | filter(compose(equal_to(3), get<1>))
                              | transform(get<0>);
```

Barry pointed out in a comment that `transform(get<0>)` is actually `ranges::views::keys`, so the code can be further simplified:

```cpp
    auto result = zip(v1, v2) | filter(compose(equal_to(3), get<1>))
                              | keys;
```

In another comment was pointed out something that I never think about: `filter` takes a projection function too, so `filter(compose(equal_to(3), get<1>))` does the same job as `filter(equal_to(3), get<1>)`:

```cpp
    auto result = zip(v1, v2) | filter(equal_to(3), get<1>)
                              | keys;
```

And finally, `get<1>` is `elements<1>` (wherever that is, I haven't found it yet :D), so we can do without Boost.Hof's `BOOST_HOF_LIFT` macro.

Comment: This particular transform is so common that it has a dedicated range adaptor for it. `elements<N>` gives you the `N`th element of a `tuple`, so this could be `elements<0>`. And then this one is also sufficiently common that there's a dedicate range adaptor for it: `keys` (and `values` for `elements<1>`)

Comment: `filter` has an overload that takes a projection, so `filter(equal_to(3), get<1>)` is equivalent to your use of `compose`